# Разворачивание одного пункта меню при сворачивании остальных

Tags: html, css, javascript

Меню подходит, только одна проблема. Пример:

1) Мы жмем на одну графу и открывается список.
2) Мы жмем на вторую графу и первый список скрывается, а второй раскрывается. То есть чтоб нельзя было открыть 2 графы одновременно. Если открываем одну, то другая скрывается (сори за корявое объяснение).

```
<html>
<head>

<!-- HEAD START HERE -->
<script language=JavaScript> 
function clickHandler() {
    var targetId, srcElement, targetElement;
    srcElement = window.event.srcElement;
    if (srcElement.className == "Outline") {
        targetId = srcElement.id + "details";
        targetElement = document.all(targetId);
        if (targetElement.style.display == "none") {
            targetElement.style.display = "";
        } else {
            targetElement.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
document.onclick = clickHandler;
</script>
<!-- HEAD END HERE -->
</head>
<body text="#FFFFFF" link="#FFFFFF" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
<!-- BODY START HERE -->
<b id=Out2 class="Outline" style="cursor: pointer; font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica; font-size:11px;">&#9658;MENU 1</b><br>
<div id=Out2details style="display:None; position:relative; left:9;">
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 1.1</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 1.2</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 1.3</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 1.4</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 1.5</a><br>
</div>
<b id=Out3 class="Outline" style="cursor: pointer;">&#9658;MENU 2</b><br>
<div id=Out3details style="display:None; position:relative; left:9;">
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 2.1</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 2.2</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 2.3</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 2.4</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 2.5</a><br>
</div>
<b id=Out4 class="Outline" style="cursor: pointer;">&#9658;MENU 3</b><br>
<div id=Out4details style="display:None; position:relative; left:9;">
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 3.1</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 3.2</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 3.3</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 3.4</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 3.5</a><br>
</div>
<b id=Out5 class="Outline" style="cursor: pointer;">&#9658;MENU 5</b><br>
<div id=Out5details style="display:None; position:relative; left:9;">
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 4.1</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 4.2</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 4.3</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 4.4</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 4.5</a><br>
</div>
<b id=Out6 class="Outline" style="cursor: pointer;">&#9658;MENU 5</b><br>
<div id=Out6details style="display:None; position:relative; left:9;">
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 5.1</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 5.2</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 5.3</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 5.4</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 5.5</a><br>
</div>
<b id=Out7 class="Outline" style="cursor: pointer;">&#9658;MENU 6</b><br>
<div id=Out7details style="display:None; position:relative; left:9;">
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 6.1</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 6.2</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 6.3</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 6.4</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 6.5</a><br>
</div>
<b id=Out8 class="Outline" style="cursor: pointer;">&#9658;MENU 7</b><br>
<div id=Out8details style="display:None; position:relative; left:9;">
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 7.1</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 7.2</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 7.3</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 7.4</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 7.5</a><br>
</div>
<b id=Out9 class="Outline" style="cursor: pointer;">&#9658;MENU 8</b><br>
<div id=Out9details style="display:None; position:relative; left:9;">
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 8.1</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 8.2</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 8.3</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 8.4</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 8.5</a><br>
</div>
<!-- BODY END HERE -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: плохое оформление

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
window.onload = function() {
function getClassed(tag,cl) {
    var allTargets = document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    var targetedTags = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < allTargets.length; i++) {
        if (allTargets[i].className == cl) {
            targetedTags.push(allTargets[i]);
        }
    }
    return targetedTags;
}

mainMenuItems = getClassed("b","Outline");

for (var k = 0; k < mainMenuItems.length; k++) {
    mainMenuItems[k].onclick = function(e){
        var targetId = this.id+"details";
        var targetElement = document.getElementById(targetId);
        var hideTags = getClassed("div", "inline");
        for (var j = 0; j < hideTags.length; j++) {
            if (hideTags[j] != targetElement) {
                hideTags[j].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        if (targetElement.style.display == "none") {
            targetElement.style.display = "";
        } else {
            targetElement.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

}
</script>
```

Да, и не забываем присвоить **class="inline"** DIV-элементам по примеру:

```
<b id="Out3" class="Outline" style="cursor: pointer;">&#9658;MENU 2</b><br>
<div id="Out3details" class="inline" style="display:None; position:relative; left:9;">
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 2.1</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 2.2</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 2.3</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 2.4</a><br>
<a href="#">&#9658;Menu 2.5</a><br>
</div>
```

Еще оптимизировать и оптимизировать, но смысл должон быть ясен.

Но лучше, быстрее и красивее (а значит и ошибок меньше) - сделать это с jQuery. Строк меньше.

**UPD:** не забывайте про кавычки **id="Out3"** - строгие html'ы не приемлют этого, и, по-моему, html5 к ним относится.